# Why does completely same function behave differently in ipython/jupyter?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, numba

I have two identical functions, say, `sum_nb` and `sum_nb2`. I define them with `@njit` decorator:

```py
from numba import njit
from timeit import timeit

@njit
def sum_nb(n=100_000_000):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s += i
    return s

@njit
def sum_nb2(n=100_000_000):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s += i
    return s
```

if I just save as script and add code to measure execution time, everything behaves nicely:

```py
print(sum_nb())
print(sum_nb2())
print(timeit(sum_nb))
print(timeit(sum_nb2))
```

The output is:

```
4999999950000000
4999999950000000
0.41249959499691613
0.4120563520118594
```

Now I open ipython console/jupyter lab and copy the first code to the cell. Then I measure code time in cells with magic:

```
In [3]: %timeit sum_nb()
240 ns ± 86.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit sum_nb2()
7.32 µs ± 90 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The same happens if in jupyter lab. How does it happen? How it works? Why does the same code have different speed?

I have ipython 7.7.0, numba 0.44.1, python 3.7.3, jupyter lab 1.0.2

Comment: Probably weirdness with the JIT compiler, if I had to guess

Comment: It seems to have decided to run sum_nb() for far more loops. Maybe this made a difference in terms of having a hotter cache or better branch prediction? Possibly minimized the JIT overhead? Manually force the same number of loops and runs and try again.

Comment: Isn't floating-point math supposed to be wonky?

Comment: @Gus it's not that I decided something. I just let %magic decide by itself how many times to run the code. However, if I run `timeit(sum_nb, number=10_000_000)` and same for `sum_nb2`, I get the results 3.1 and 99.3 respectevely.

Comment: I can confirm the results you are seeing. Note that a function that just has `return (n + 1) * n // 2` runs about as fast as the faster results (a bit faster actually), so I'm inclined to assume Numba (or LLVM) uses this optimisation behind the scenes for the faster results, and performs a "standard" loop for the slower results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the result of inconsistent caching behavior. Jupyter even suggests this as an issue: `The slowest run took 74.96 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.`

On my machine, the function with the caching behavior runs in ~240ns and the one without runs in ~50μs.

The only way I've found to make the behavior consistent between the two functions is by pulling `n=100_000_000` into the body of the function which makes both functions ~240ns.